# Pythonic way to setup fixture for test

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a fixture with `scope="session"`, as it is webserver which should be started and finished only once for all tests. But I want to clear cache before running a new test, so I made fixture that gets webserver and cleans cache:

```
import pytest


class Webserver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = []
        print("Init server")

    def start(self):
        print("Start server")

    def stop(self):
        print("Stop server")

    def query(self):
        self.cache.append("some data")

    def clear_cache(self):
        self.cache.clear()
        print("Clear cache")


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def mock_server():
    server = Webserver()
    server.start()
    yield server
    server.stop()


@pytest.fixture
def mock_server_with_clean_cache(mock_server):
    mock_server.clear_cache()
    return mock_server


def test_basic_1(mock_server_with_clean_cache):
    mock_server_with_clean_cache.query()
    assert len(mock_server_with_clean_cache.cache) == 1


def test_basic_2(mock_server_with_clean_cache):
    mock_server_with_clean_cache.query()
    assert len(mock_server_with_clean_cache.cache) == 1
```

I believe there must be a better and more convenient way to do this. So is there any?

Answer (score 0):

You can add autouse=True to the mock_server_with_clean_cache fixture.

This way you don't have to add it to the test and pytest will run it each test.

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_server_with_clean_cache(mock_server):
    mock_server.clear_cache()

def test_1():
    # mock_server_with_clean_cache will run and clear the cache before test starts
```